# IOS app works in 4.3 but crashes with SIGABRT in main on 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, addsubview, sigabrt

I was developing an app for iOS 4.3 back in the summer on my iPhone 4 and things were working well.  I put that project on the back burner while I was relocating jobs.  With the release of iOS 5 I updated both my Xcode and iOS SDK to 4.2 and 5.0 respectively and I also bought a new iPod Touch running 5.0 for developing.

My app still works in the iPhone 4.3 Simulator (unfortunately I don't have the iPhone 4 to test on anymore), but it crashes consistently on the iPhone 5.0 Simulator, as well as the iPod Touch.

The error happens when I try to load a subview and goes to main and says it crashes with a SIGABRT.  Below is the segment of code where the crash occurs:

```
-(IBAction) showView:(id) sender{   
    if (self.tViewController == nil) {
        self.tViewController = [[TViewController alloc] init];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tViewController animated:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                         forView:self.view
                         cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:tViewController.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

When I step through and reach this line:

```
[self.view addSubview:tViewController.view];
```

It crashes, and jumps to main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

And shows a 'SIGABRT' being received at this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I've read that the error is coming from something being released twice.  But in my 'showView' function, I don't see where I could have done that.  Unless the addSubview method does something I'm unaware of.

Also, why is this error happening in 5.0 and not 4.3?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you make sure that tViewController (and tViewController.view) is loaded, valid, not-over-released, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure I know exactly what you're asking (I'm still a bit new at this)  When I step through and watch the local variables, this is what I see (plus some other values for other variables but I'm omitting them for now):  self NHL_StatsViewController * 0x685e500  tViewController TViewController * 0x6e02740  UIViewController UIViewController {...}  _view UIView * 0x0  So the tViewController is valid I guess, but the view hasn't loaded.   Does that answer what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) showView:(id) sender{   
    if (self.tViewController == nil) {
        self.tViewController = [[TViewController alloc] init];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tViewController animated:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                     forView:self.view
                     cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:tViewController.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

You have already push this view using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:tViewController animated:YES]` then why are you adding it to main view using `[self.view addSubview:tViewController.view]` remove this line of code.

Comment: When I remove that line of code, my tViewController view doesn't load, and instead my current view just flips left to itself

Comment: self.tViewController = [[TViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Your tViewController nib(xib) file name without extension" bundle:nil]; use this.

Comment: Still the same results.  In fact, when I try to load the view a second time, it gets that same SIGABRT error (I'm assuming that's a totally unrelated error since I'm trying to load a view that I've already attempted to load)

Comment: you were right, pushing the view twice was my problem, although I had to remove the navigationController push, not the addSubview.  I don't know why I ever put that navigationcontroller push there since I haven't been using a navigationController for anything.  Thanks for the help